# Setup AWS OIDC across accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, amazon-iam, openid-connect

I have 2 AWS accounts:

**Account A**: It contains an Identity Provider (IdP).

**Account B**: It has an IAM role (ROLE B). This role is also configured to allow assuming the role using the WebIdentityAssume against the Identity Provider set up in Account A.

```
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
        },
        "Action": [
            "sts:TagSession",
            "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:my-org/my-repo:*"
            },
            "StringEquals": {
                "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
            }
    }
```

Then I use this action to do OIDC authentication:

```
    - name: Login to AWS use OIDC flow
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
      role-to-assume: <ROLE_B_ARN>
      role-duration-seconds: 1200
      role-session-name: OidcSession
```

I get error "Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"

My question is that *is it possible to do OIDC across AWS accounts*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Role B (in account B) cannot use identity providers defined in another AWS account.

You can either:

(1) Create and use an identity provider in account B

(2) Create a role in account A that can be assumed with web identity, then use [role chaining](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#iam-term-role-chaining) to assume a role in account B that trusts this role in account A. (In other words, assume role A, then assume role B using role A).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the role chaining. I can successfully authenticate using  role A, but then when I try to assume role B using role A again it says 'not authorized to perform'. I'm quite sure that I configure the trust policy correct. Do you get it successful with the second option? I don't know what I miss.

Comment: @patppd you need to make sure Role A has permission for the sts:AssumeRole operation for Role B AND that the trust document for role B allows it to be assumed by role A. In the GitHub action, you may have to explicitly set the access key ID/secret/session token as inputs to chain to role B. Alternatively you can forego using the action altogether and just use the AWS CLI to do that manually. You can also configure profiles to make it a bit more seamless (a profile to assume role A and a profile for role B that specified the other profile as the `source_profile`). Try to do it locally first.

Comment: I now can do role chaining. With forcing environment, aws-cli configure profile doesn't override. Thank you!!, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Sytech I am having similar issue. Could you please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76503978/not-authorized-to-perform-stsassumerolewithwebidentity

Comment: Note for option (2): Role chaining limits your AWS CLI or AWS API role session to a maximum of one hour and can't be increased. So depending on how long the actions you perform as role B take, option (2) might not be feasible for you. For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html

[This](https://medium.com/@ummusalma/open-id-connect-oidc-from-bitbucket-to-aws-using-assume-role-c885c393bf15) blog post that covers scenario (2).